# how to allow use of a specific character - REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm actually using this code to check if my string have any special characters:

```
var regex = /[^\w\s!?]/g;

if (regex.test(message)) {
   notify('error', 'Special characters are not allowed!');
   return;
}
```

but I want to allow '/' too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add forward slash to the character class:

```js
var regex = /[^\w\s!?/]/g;
var message = 'hello/world';
if (regex.test(message)) {
    console.log('error', 'Special characters are not allowed!');
}
else {
    console.log('allowed');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape characters within regexes.

```
var regex = /[^\w\s!?/]/g;

if (regex.test(message)) {
   notify('error', 'Special characters are not allowed!');
   return;
}
```

And, as noted below, most special characters lose their special meaning within brackets. I've corrected the snippet.

Comment: Tiny note: a `/` that appears inside a character class doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @CRice I believe only square brackets and backslash would need escaping inside a character class.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well, most things lose their special meaning inside square brackets. You do need to escape in special circumstances where the character does have a special meaning inside character class - an *opening* square bracket doesn't and can work, but a *closing* square bracket means end of the character class and should be escaped. Also, a dash indicates a range, unless put in the beginning or the end. A caret in the beginning will negate. And a backslash will escape. Although, reading `/[[\]]/` is slightly odd, so you might escape both. Sometimes escaping improves readability.

Comment: @vlaz You're right, I commented too quickly above.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
regex = /[^\w\s!?/]/g;
```

Do you need any help?